# Read text file content into matrix based on condition

Tags: file-io, octave

I have a text files of this format:

```
Food
Fruits1     [heading]
    Apple    [value]
    Mango    [value]
    Orange   [value]
Veg1        [heading]
    Potato   [value]
    Lettuce  [value]
```

I want to load this into **Octave** as a matrix of this format:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Item | Fruits1 | Apple | Mango | Orange | Veg1 | Potato | Lettuce
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |         |       |       |        |      |        |         
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Hence, I need a matrix of size = 2x(n+m+1);  where n = number of [heading], m = number of [value].

How can I use *fgetl* to read each line from the text file and store into a matrix satisfying the above condition? Any better ideas?

Thanks!

Edit: Code:-

```
fid = fopen('food.txt','r');
num = 1;
  if (fid < 0) 
    printf('Error:could not open file\n')
  else
    while ~feof(fid),
    line = fgetl(fid);
    arr=[line;];     
    num=num+1;
    end;
        fclose(fid)
  end;
```

Comment: This is not trivial. You should show us what you have tried, to motivate us to make it better.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Point noted! I have added what I have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Matrix is not possible because your strings doesn't have the same length. It's only possible to put it into a cell. But I would recommend a structured list.

```
fid = fopen('list.txt');

while 1
  tmp = fgetl(fid);
  if ~ischar(tmp)
    % end of file
    break
  end

  if strcmp(deblank(tmp), 'Food')
    # this can't be empty
    listObj.('item') = 'Food';
  else
    tmp = cell2mat(regexp(deblank(tmp),'(\w+)','tokens'));
    if strcmp(tmp{1,2}, 'heading')
      head = tmp{1,1};
    else
      listObj.(head).(tmp{1,1}) = str2double(tmp{1,2});
    end
  end
end
```

You can access it much better.

```
>> stackoverflow
>> listObj
listObj =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

    item = Food
    Fruits1 =

      scalar structure containing the fields:

        Apple =                    3
        Mango =                    4
        Orange =                    1

    Veg1 =

      scalar structure containing the fields:

        Potato =                    8
        Lettuce =                    0


>> listObj.Fruits1.Apple
ans =                    3
>> listObj.Veg1.Lettuce
ans =                    0
>>
```

But take care about your input file, it has to be strictly formatted. My example file looks like this

```
Food
Fruits1     [heading]
    Apple    3
    Mango    4
    Orange   1
Veg1        [heading]
    Potato   8
    Lettuce  0
```